# MySQL sharding and stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sharding, mysql-fabric

Is there a way to dispatch stored procedure invocation on particular shard, based on sharding key (passed as procedure argument or somehow separately)?

For example we have a table, sharded between 3 nodes using HASH sharding strategy. All rows with key `A` are stored on `node 1`. I'd like to be sure that when I run `procedure(A)`, it applies on `node1`.

We are going to use Mysql Fabric tool, but other options are considered too.

Comment: This is a better fit for the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) as this is infrastructure related and not programming per-se.